# Java - Accessing JLabel inside JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I have a GUI that holds panels containing both a component and a label relating to this component. The labels are created and never changed, so at the moment, I just have their constructor in the `JPanel.add()` method.

```
    //add label
    toServerPanel.add(new JLabel("Your Message"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    //add component
    toServerPanel.add(toServer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

This works fine, and they are fine as anonymous objects but I would now like to change the text colour of some or all of the labels within the application. Seeing as they are anonymous objects they can't be accessed by their variable name, but at the same time I don't want to have to created endless `JLabel` variables.

In the current situation, is the a method or function to access the `JLabel` objects by checking for objects inside the `JPanel`?
Alternatively, is there some kind of loop that could affect all the `JLabel` objects on the GUI?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: *"The labels are created and never changed"* - So this might seem like a stupid statement, then why don't you provide a getter in the `toServerPanel` to retrieve them?  You could maintain them in a `List` or event a `Map` if you wanted to look them up by some identifier?

Answer (score 6):

You could loop through all components of the Panel:

```
for (Component jc : toServerPanel.getComponents()) {
    if ( jc instanceof JLabel ) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Here is a minimal working example I have created and tested. The color of the two JLabels are randomly assigned when you click the button:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

public class ComponentTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private Random r;

    public ComponentTest() {
        super("TestFrame");

        r = new Random();
        mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.add(new JLabel("I'm a Label!"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainPanel.add(new JLabel("I'm a label, too!"), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton triggerButton = new JButton("Click me!");
        triggerButton.addActionListener(this);
        mainPanel.add(triggerButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setContentPane(mainPanel);

        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Color c = new Color(r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256));
        for (Component jc : mainPanel.getComponents()) {
            if (jc instanceof JLabel) {
                JLabel label = (JLabel) jc;
                label.setForeground(c);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ComponentTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, tried this and the labels seem unaffected. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: @marcuthh I have added a working example. If a label is not affected, is it possible that the Label is not a direct child - e.g. wrapped in another Panel?

Answer (score 1):

If your `JLabel` is the only one component in your panel, you can do something like that:

```
JLabel lbl = (JLabel)toServerPanel.getComponent(0);
```

And the handle `lbl`.

Comment: Thanks for this, could this kind of solution be put into a loop that would do the same to all panels?

Comment: For sure, you also can use the methog [getComponents()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents--) to iterate in all components.